# Can you explain css code like below?

Tags: css

```
margin-left:-500px;margin-right:-500px;
```

What's the meaning ?Why do it like that ?

Comment: I think it's a hacky way to move the content 500 hundred pixels to the left.

Comment: Whats the context? Can you show all th css?

Comment: RageZ, Shouldnt the Margin-right cancel the Margin left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably cancels out the 500px padding on the parent element:

```
<div style="padding-left: 500px; padding-right: 500px;">
   <div style="margin-left:-500px;margin-right:-500px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Read this nice article: [The Definitive Guide to Using Negative Margins](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/)

Negative margins are usually applied in small doses but as you’ll see later on, it’s capable of so much more. A few things to note about negative margins are:

**1. They are extremely valid CSS**

I’m not kidding on this one. W3C even says that, “Negative values for 
margin properties are allowed…” ‘Nuff said. Check out the article for 
more details.

**2. Negative margins are not a hack**

This is especially true. It’s because of not understanding negative margins 
properly that it got its hackish image. It only becomes a hack if you use it 
to fix an error you made elsewhere.

**3. It goes with the flow**

It does not break the flow of the page if applied to elements without floats. 
So if you use a negative margin to nudge an element upwards, all succeeding 
elements will be nudged as well.

**4. It is highly compatible**

Negative margins are wholly supported across all modern browsers (and IE6 
in most cases).

**5. It reacts differently when floats are applied**

Negative margins are not your everyday CSS so they should be applied with 
care.

**6. Dreamweaver doesn’t understand it**

Negative margins don’t show up in the Design View of DW. Why are you even 
checking your site in Design View anyway?

Comment: +1 - nice summary.  I've edited to stop the code highlighting.

Comment: Dominic has sorted it, looks much nicer now.

Answer (score 0):

i read once (reference forgotten) that negative margins are supposed to send elements out of the way, sending them to the left most side of the browser. It is meant to hide elements out of the browser if you dont want to use

`style="display:none"`

does the element with the negative margins behave this way?

Comment: Yep - though I'd expect it to have a bigger negative value than -500 (you tend to see values like -9999px for this). I've seen this technique used where menu items are meant to be displayed as images, but the text was wanted for people browsing without images, or with styles turned off.